# Seperate Ringtone for Unknown Caller (Android 7)

Tags: contacts, ringtone

In Android 7, how can I set a separate ringtone for callers who are not in my contact list? I still want to receive the call but I want to know if it is someone in my contact list or not before answering.

Comment: Adding the model and specific device could be useful, but I believe the only way is to set the default ringtone to what you want for unknown callers then set a different ringtone for each contact manually (could be the same for all contacts but still have to do it manually).

Comment: @acejavelin Samsung S7

Comment: @beeshyams :) What "automation approach" are you referring to?